# Type Error: Positional Arguments with pandas.apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Problem Statement:

A pandas dataframe column series, `same_group` needs to be created from booleans according to the values of two existing columns, `row` and `col`.  The row needs to show True if both values have similar values (intersecting values) in a dictionary `memberships`, and False otherwise (no intersecting values).  Using `pd.apply()` give the error:

```
TypeError: ('checkGrouping() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given', 'occurred at index row')
```

### Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
n = np.nan
memberships = {'a':['vowel'], 'b':['consonant'], 'c':['consonant'], 'd':['consonant'], 'e':['vowel'], 'y':['consonant', 'vowel']}

congruent = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(  
         {'row': ['a','b','c','d','e','y'],
            'a': [ n, -.8,-.6,-.3, .8, .01],
            'b': [-.8,  n, .5, .7,-.9, .01],
            'c': [-.6, .5,  n, .3, .1, .01],
            'd': [-.3, .7, .3,  n, .2, .01],
            'e': [ .8,-.9, .1, .2,  n, .01],
            'y': [ .01, .01, .01, .01,  .01, n],
       }).set_index('row')
congruent.columns.names = ['col']
```

[image: snippet of dataframe cs]

```
cs = congruent.stack().to_frame()
cs.columns = ['score']
cs.reset_index(inplace=True)
cs.head(6)
```

[image: snippet of dataframe cs stacked]

### The Desired Goal:

[image: finest drawing of added pandas column]

### Make boolean series:

#### attempt 0:

```
def checkGrouping(row, col):
    if row in memberships.keys() and col in memberships.keys():
        return memberships[row].intersection(set(memberships[col]))
    else:
        return np.nan


cs['same_group'] = cs.apply(checkGrouping,args=(cs['row'], cs['col']))
```

It looked like I'm providing the args to `checkGrouping` so why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# create a series to make it convenient to map
# make each member a set so I can intersect later
lkp = pd.Series(memberships).apply(set)

# get number of rows and columns
# map the sets to column and row indices
n, m = congruent.shape
c = congruent.columns.to_series().map(lkp).values
r = congruent.index.to_series().map(lkp).values
```

---

```
print(c)
[{'vowel'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'vowel'}
 {'consonant', 'vowel'}]
```

---

```
print(r)
[{'vowel'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'vowel'}
 {'consonant', 'vowel'}]
```

---

```
# use np.repeat, np.tile, zip to create cartesian product
# this should match index after stacking
# apply set intersection for each pair
# empty sets are False, otherwise True
same = [
    bool(set.intersection(*tup))
    for tup in zip(np.repeat(r, m), np.tile(c, n))
]

# use dropna=False to ensure we maintain the
# cartesian product I was expecting
# then slice with boolean list I created
# and dropna
congruent.stack(dropna=False)[same].dropna()

row  col
a    e      0.80
     y      0.01
b    c      0.50
     d      0.70
     y      0.01
c    b      0.50
     d      0.30
     y      0.01
d    b      0.70
     c      0.30
     y      0.01
e    a      0.80
     y      0.01
y    a      0.01
     b      0.01
     c      0.01
     d      0.01
     e      0.01
dtype: float64
```

---

Produce wanted result

```
congruent.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='Score') \
    .assign(same_group=np.array(same).astype(int)).dropna()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

apply will pass you along the column or row it is iterating against. Thus your function `checkGrouping` will receive that argument. So it's correct prototype will be something like:

```
def checkGrouping(s, row, col):
    if row in memberships.keys() and col in memberships.keys():
        return memberships[row].intersection(set(memberships[col]))
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Comment: PS: I think what you try to accomplish should be done with another approach than a procedural apply, but that's another story, here I just address your question about the number of arguments error

Comment: The question is really about using apply correctly, and I'm not.  I get a new error: `TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed",   
u'occurred at index 0')`.  So how am I supposed to perform a lookup on a series value?  Should I not be using apply?

Comment: Row and cool arguments you pass along are series. Per se they are not cells / scalar as I think you are expecting. Your new error comes from the fact that now you do series in m.keys(). Again the code doesn't reflect your intention. You should not use apply but instead do you vector operations directly against the dataframe

Comment: If you have any ideas, maybe you could answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621279/vectorized-lookups-of-pandas-series-to-a-dictionary