# Vectorized Lookups of Pandas Series to a Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### Problem Statement:

A pandas dataframe column series, `same_group` needs to be created from booleans according to the values of two existing columns, `row` and `col`.  The row needs to show True if both cells across a row have similar values (intersecting values) in a dictionary `memberships`, and False otherwise (no intersecting values).  How do I do this in a vectorized way (not using apply)?

### Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
n = np.nan
memberships = {
    'a':['vowel'],
    'b':['consonant'],
    'c':['consonant'],
    'd':['consonant'],
    'e':['vowel'],
    'y':['consonant', 'vowel']
}

congruent = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(  
         {'row': ['a','b','c','d','e','y'],
            'a': [ n, -.8,-.6,-.3, .8, .01],
            'b': [-.8,  n, .5, .7,-.9, .01],
            'c': [-.6, .5,  n, .3, .1, .01],
            'd': [-.3, .7, .3,  n, .2, .01],
            'e': [ .8,-.9, .1, .2,  n, .01],
            'y': [ .01, .01, .01, .01,  .01, n],
       }).set_index('row')
congruent.columns.names = ['col']
```

[image: snippet of dataframe cs]

```
cs = congruent.stack().to_frame()
cs.columns = ['score']
cs.reset_index(inplace=True)
cs.head(6)
```

[image: snippet of dataframe cs stacked]

### The Desired Goal:

[image: finest drawing of added pandas column]

How do I accomplish creating this new column based on a lookup on a dictionary?

Note that I'm trying to find intersection, not equivalence.  For example, row 4 should have a `same_group` of 1, since `a` and `y` are both vowels (despite that `y` is "sometimes a vowel" and thus belongs to groups consonant and vowel).

Comment: Convert your membership dict to a data frame that you can then use to index row and column

Comment: I think I'm done editing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create a series to make it convenient to map
# make each member a set so I can intersect later
lkp = pd.Series(memberships).apply(set)

# get number of rows and columns
# map the sets to column and row indices
n, m = congruent.shape
c = congruent.columns.to_series().map(lkp).values
r = congruent.index.to_series().map(lkp).values
```

---

```
print(c)
[{'vowel'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'vowel'}
 {'consonant', 'vowel'}]
```

---

```
print(r)
[{'vowel'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'consonant'} {'vowel'}
 {'consonant', 'vowel'}]
```

---

```
# use np.repeat, np.tile, zip to create cartesian product
# this should match index after stacking
# apply set intersection for each pair
# empty sets are False, otherwise True
same = [
    bool(set.intersection(*tup))
    for tup in zip(np.repeat(r, m), np.tile(c, n))
]

# use dropna=False to ensure we maintain the
# cartesian product I was expecting
# then slice with boolean list I created
# and dropna
congruent.stack(dropna=False)[same].dropna()

row  col
a    e      0.80
     y      0.01
b    c      0.50
     d      0.70
     y      0.01
c    b      0.50
     d      0.30
     y      0.01
d    b      0.70
     c      0.30
     y      0.01
e    a      0.80
     y      0.01
y    a      0.01
     b      0.01
     c      0.01
     d      0.01
     e      0.01
dtype: float64
```

---

Produce wanted result

```
congruent.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='Score') \
    .assign(same_group=np.array(same).astype(int)).dropna()
```

[image]

Comment: What does it mean when `r` and `c` show only `nan`?  Are the values in `row` and `col` not being mapped to `lkp`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew column or row names are not in membership dictionary.  Could be a type issue, like int versus str.  I need more information to be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea:** let's convert your lists of `['vowel', 'consonant']` to binary `[1, 2]` and use bitwise operations:

**Setup:**

```
In [138]: lkp2 = pd.Series(memberships) \
                   .apply(pd.Series) \
                   .replace({'vowel':1, 'consonant':2}) \
                   .sum(1) \
                   .astype('uint8')

In [139]: lkp2
Out[139]:
a    1  # 'vovel'
b    2  # 'consonant'
c    2  # 'consonant'
d    2  # 'consonant'
e    1  # 'vovel'
y    3  # 1 | 2 = 3 - both bits are set
dtype: uint8
```

**Solution:**

```
In [140]: cs['same_group'] = np.bitwise_and(cs.row.map(lkp2), cs.col.map(lkp2)).ne(0).mul(1)

In [141]: cs
Out[141]:
   row col  score  same_group
0    a   b  -0.80           0
1    a   c  -0.60           0
2    a   d  -0.30           0
3    a   e   0.80           1
4    a   y   0.01           1
5    b   a  -0.80           0
6    b   c   0.50           1
7    b   d   0.70           1
8    b   e  -0.90           0
9    b   y   0.01           1
10   c   a  -0.60           0
11   c   b   0.50           1
12   c   d   0.30           1
13   c   e   0.10           0
14   c   y   0.01           1
15   d   a  -0.30           0
16   d   b   0.70           1
17   d   c   0.30           1
18   d   e   0.20           0
19   d   y   0.01           1
20   e   a   0.80           1
21   e   b  -0.90           0
22   e   c   0.10           0
23   e   d   0.20           0
24   e   y   0.01           1
25   y   a   0.01           1
26   y   b   0.01           1
27   y   c   0.01           1
28   y   d   0.01           1
29   y   e   0.01           1
30   y   y   0.00           1
```

**Timing:** against 3.1M rows DF:

```
In [180]: cs = pd.concat([cs] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [181]: cs.shape
Out[181]: (3100000, 3)

In [182]: %timeit np.bitwise_and(cs.row.map(lkp2), cs.col.map(lkp2)).ne(0).mul(1)
1 loop, best of 3: 466 ms per loop
```

Comment: The problem here is I'm trying to find intersection, not equivalence.  For example, row 4 should have a `same_group` of 1, since `a` and `y` are both vowels (despite that `y` is "sometimes a vowel" and thus belongs to groups consonant and vowel).

Comment: @ThomasMatthew, what do you think about this new solution, which uses bitwise operations - it should much faster

Comment: I like the bitwise operations if it means greater efficiency.  However, in my actual data set I have up to 300 different groups, not just two here with vowel and consonant.  In that case, can I modify the replace method in defining `lkp2` to be`.replace({'group1':1, 'group2':2, 'group3':3 ... groupN:N}) \` so it can work with larger groups?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew, no, in this case it's not going to work because `2^300` is far beyond a maximum of `np.uint64`... Next time please put such details into your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt:

I sliced the data using iloc. memberships[my_slice] gives me the value in dictionary memberships and int(memberships[my_slice]) returns 1 if true and 0 if false making it easy to append that number directly in the new column same_group.

```
grp = []
for i in range(len(cs)):
    if 'y' not in cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][0|1]:
        grp.append(int(memberships[cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][0]] == memberships[cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][1]]))
        i+=1
    else:
        grp.append(int(memberships[cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][0|1]] == memberships[cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][0|1]]))
        i+=1
same_grp = pd.Series(grp)       
cs = pd.concat([cs, same_grp], axis = 1)
cs.columns = ['row', 'col', 'score', 'same_grp']  
cs.head(10)
```

I used the condition (if 'y' not in cs.iloc[i,[0,1]][0|1]) to handle the fact that y can have two values.